# What does "ret.push_back(vector<int>());" mean?

Tags: c++

Can you tell me what `ret.push_back(vector<int>());` means exactly? The whole code is given below:

```cpp
struct TreeNode
{
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
```

```cpp
struct Solution 
{
    vector <vector <int>> ret;
    void buildVector(TreeNode *root, int depth)
    {
        if(root==NULL) return;
        if(ret.size()==depth) ret.push_back(vector<int>());
        ret[depth].push_back(root->val);
        buildVector(root->left,depth+1);
        buildVector(root->right,depth+1);
    }
    vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode *A) 
    {
        buildVector(A,0);
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: `ret` is a data member, a `vector` of `vector`s. You fetch here an inner `vector`, by subscripting -  `ret[depth]`. Then you call a `push_back()` on an inner `vector`, placing a new value into the fetched inner `vector` - `root->val`.

Comment: What is exactly happening there? What data is going inside the vector of vectors 'ret' at "if(ret.size()==depth) ret.push_back(vector<int>());"?

Comment: `vector<int>()` calls the default constructor of `vector<int>`. An empty vector is pushed

Comment: @Himakar -- How would *you* place an empty vector inside the vector of vectors?  Now compare that to the code you are seeing.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

`vector <vector<int>> ret;` means `ret` is a vector of vectors. To understand this easily, vector is a dynamic array. So basically, `ret` is an array of arrays.

So, in this case, `ret.push_back(vector<int>())` means you are adding a new array to your array of arrays.

Comment: What is there in that new array/vector? Is it empty?

Comment: Don't use "array" in this context, that's confusing. C++ has an `std::array` type, but that cannot be empty. A C++ `std::vector` can be empty, and by default is empty.